# How to handle Null value

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following if statement:

```
if ((product.EmailType.Contains("cafe", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
     || product.EmailType.Contains("vendor", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    && product.Supplier.Supplier_Type.Contains("Support"))
{
    // Do some stuff
}
```

Basically if `EmailType` contains a specific value or a different specific value, and the `SupplierType` is "Support", do something.

However, it is very common for the `Supplier_Type` to be null. With how it is above it throws an exception.

How do I account for it possibly being null? If it's null it should evaluate the whole if statement as false and move on.

I tried null coalescing on the final line but I get an error

> Operator ?? cannot be applied to type bool and bool

```
if ((product.EmailType.Contains("cafe", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
     || product.EmailType.Contains("vendor", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    && (product.Supplier.Supplier_Type.Contains("Support") ?? false))
{
    // Do some stuff
}
```

I also tried null handling by writing the final line as the following, but get the same error:

```
&& product.Supplier.Supplier_Type?.Contains("Support")
```

Comment: ... use both ....

Comment: @Selvin write an answer.

Comment: May I ask why you are using 'Contains' checks with string values, instead of relying on something stronger like an enum? Notice that with a nullable enum property, you could do this: `product.Supplier.Supplier_Type == SupplierType.Support` and it would naturally handle your null case for you, returning false.

Comment: `&& product.Supplier.Supplier_Type?.Contains("Support") ?? false`. The `?.` says _if Supplier_Type is null, skip the call to `Contains` and just evaluate the whole expression as `null`_. The final `??` says _if the `?.Contains` call is null, make the whole thing `false`_. Same as what @Selvin said (but in more words)

Comment: don't forget about braces ... && precede ??

Comment: Thank you, using both worked. I won't go into much detail since I have a solution, but the Supplier_Type can be set by the user to any string, so I don't want to use enums.

Answer (score 0):

Break it down

```
if (containsAny(product.EmailType, "cafe", "vendor") && containsAny(product.Supplier.Supplier_Type, "support"))
{
    //Do some stuff
}
// Scenario specific local function for cleanliness and brevity
bool containsAny(string? input, params string[] searchFor) =>
    input is not null && searchFor.Any(s => input.Contains(s, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

Answer (score 0):

Lots of options. Here are a few.

```
if (  (product.EmailType.Contains("cafe", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
    || product.EmailType.Contains("vendor", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    && product.Supplier.Supplier_Type != null
    && product.Supplier.Supplier_Type.Contains("Support"))
{
    //Do some stuff
}
```

Using null coalescing:

```
if (  (product.EmailType.Contains("cafe", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
    || product.EmailType.Contains("vendor", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    && (product.Supplier.Supplier_Type?.Contains("Support") ?? false))
{
    //Do some stuff
}
```

Using pattern matching and variables:

```
var targetEmailTypes = new[]{"cafe", "vendor"};
if (product.EmailType is string emailType 
    && targetEmailTypes.Any(t => emailType.Contains(t, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    && product.Supplier.Supplier_Type is string supplierType
    && supplierType.Contains("Support"))
{
    //Do some stuff
}
```